# Is Chromium spying my keyboard?

Tags: privacy, chrome, chromium

I just typed into Eclipse (a different process):

```
enum State {
}
```

Then I wanted to check about code conventions regarding those enums. So I typed into the address bar of Chromium "Java convention". The second search suggestion from Chromium was "Java convention enum". I didn't search for enum before. I really don't believe in such coincidences and suspect Chromium spying in my activities outside of its process. Is there evidence for this or is this just one big coincidence?

Comment: e is reasonably high alphabetically, and enums are not rare. Keep your tinfoil handy, but a keylogger in open source seems like a poor gamble for a big company.

Comment: I know, this is close to tinfoil land, but Chromium is a big source and Google plays a huge role. If nobody else did experience anything like that, I leave the tinfoil for now.

Comment: I don't even use Java, but after reading this question, I typed "Java convention" in my Safari browser and the first Google search suggestion was "Java convention enum". It's very unlikely that *Safari* would be reporting my activities over to Google, so I'd say leave the tinfoil off (if Google is indeed doing spying, it's probably spying on what people are searching for on Google, and found that people are searching for "Java convention enum" a lot).

Comment: @TariqAli Ok, I did the same, opening a Firefox behind TOR. Google does indeed suggest that as a second hit. So I agree it's just a coincidence. I'll leave the tinfoil for now.

Comment: There are a lot of explanations for this, but basically yes, you are being probed under the pretext of your own ease-of-search. Happens in many situations.